# Kotlin state flows not emitting in unit test with view model scope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm new to Kotlin Coroutines and Flows and unit testing them. I have a pretty simple test:

```
@Test
fun debounce(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val state = MutableStateFlow("hello")
    val debouncedState = state.debounce(500).stateIn(this, SharingStarted.Eagerly, "bla")

    assertThat(debouncedState.value).isEqualTo("bla")

    state.value = "good bye"

    // not yet...
    assertThat(debouncedState.value).isEqualTo("bla")

    delay(600)

    // now!
    assertThat(debouncedState.value).isEqualTo("good bye")

    // cannot close the state flows :(
    cancel("DONE")
}
```

It works just fine (except that I cannot stop it, but that's a different issue).

Next, I want to test my `ViewModel` which includes the exact same state flows. It's basically the same code above, but I thought it should run in the same scope as `viewModel.someMutableStateFlow` so I tried to run it on `viewModelScope`:

```
@Test
fun debounce(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val viewModel = MyViewModel()

    // in view model the state and debouncedState are defined the same way as above
    val state = viewModel.someMutableStateFlow
    val debouncedState = state.debounce(500).stateIn(viewModel.viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, "bla")

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Below is the same code as in previous example //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

    assertThat(debouncedState.value).isEqualTo("bla")

    state.value = "good bye"

    // not yet...
    assertThat(debouncedState.value).isEqualTo("bla")

    delay(600)

    // now!
    assertThat(debouncedState.value).isEqualTo("good bye")

    // cannot close the state flows :(
    cancel("DONE")
}
```

But this time the `debouncedState.value` is never changed, it stays `bla` all the time! Nothing is emitted from those states.

Does this have something to do with the fact that I am using `viewModelScope` and maybe it is not running?

Some explanation about what's going on here would be great.

Answer (score 1):

From [this documentation about setting the Main dispatcher](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test#setting-main-dispatcher):

> However, some APIs such as viewModelScope use a hardcoded Main dispatcher under the hood.

It then describes how to replace the Main dispatcher with a TestDispatcher:

```
class HomeViewModelTest {
    @Test
    fun settingMainDispatcher() = runTest {
        val testDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)

        try {
            val viewModel = HomeViewModel()
            viewModel.loadMessage() // Uses testDispatcher, runs its coroutine eagerly
            assertEquals("Greetings!", viewModel.message.value)
        } finally {
            Dispatchers.resetMain()
        }
    }
}
```

To quote the article:

> If the Main dispatcher has been replaced with a TestDispatcher, any newly-created TestDispatchers will automatically use the scheduler from the Main dispatcher, including the StandardTestDispatcher created by runTest if no other dispatcher is passed to it.

The documentation also describes how to make a test rule so you don't have to do this in each test.